# Java: '.class' expected error when passing array to function

Tags: java, arrays, parameter-passing

I'm taking a java class, but have been away from it for a bit.

Trying to get this sorting program to work:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Assignment1 
{
   private int[] nums;
   private int[] ast;

   private int n;

   public void sort(int[] vals)
   {
      this.nums = vals;
      n = vals.length;
      this.ast = new int[n];
      merges(0, n - 1);
   }   

   private void merges(int bot, int top)
   {
      if (bot < top)
      {
         int mid = bot + (top - bot) / 2;
         merges(bot, mid);
         merges(mid + 1, top);
         merge(bot, mid, top);
      }
   }

   private void merge(int bot, int mid, int top)
   {
      for (int i = bot; i <= top; i++)
      {
         ast[i] = nums[i];
      }
      int i = bot;
      int j = mid + 1;
      int k = bot;
      while (i <= mid && i <= top)
      {
         if (ast[i] <= ast[j])
         {
            nums[k] = ast[i];
            i++;
         }
         else
         {
            nums[k] = ast[j];
            j++;
         }
         k++;
      }
      while (i <= mid)
      {
         nums[k] = ast[i];
         k++;
         i++;
      }
   }

   private void show()
   {
      System.out.print("Sorted Array:  ");
      for(int l=0;l<nums.length;l++)
      {
         System.out.print(nums[l] + "  ");
      }

   }
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      Assignment1 a = new Assignment1();
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("\nArray Size: ");
      int s = scan.nextInt();
      int[] array = new int[s];
      for(int x=0;x<s;x++)
      {
         System.out.print("Enter Element " + (x + 1) + ":");
         array[x] = scan.nextInt();
      }


      a.sort(array[]);
      a.show();
   }
}
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
Assignment1.java:82: error: '.class' expected
  a.sort(array[]);
```

I know it's something basic eluding me, but the basics are the things that are most hazy...

Comment: just array without []

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, being sarcastic and critical is not helpful. Just let him know here he is wrong instead of criticizing.

Comment: @ylun Sotirios Delimanolis' questions are valid and worthwhile. If the OP reflects and answers them, he can arrive at the conclusion on his own.

Comment: I actually had it as (array) first.  I only changed it because I was getting an error while running the program.  So with the (array) fixed I get an 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at Assignment1.merge(Assignment1.java:39)
 at Assignment1.merges(Assignment1.java:24)
 at Assignment1.merges(Assignment1.java:23)
 at Assignment1.sort(Assignment1.java:14)
 at Assignment1.main(Assignment1.java:82)

Comment: @ShengLong916 After attempting to debug your new problem, you may wish to open a new question dedicated to it rather than lumping it all here. An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means what it says and you should search for possible places where an array index may be out of bounds. Temporary print-outs and stepping in the debugger (if you have one available) can help pin that type of problem down quickly.

Comment: Figured it out Thanks Jason!

Comment: @ShengLong916 You should accept the answer below that you find most helpful. You can do this by clicking the large checkmark next to the answer. Closing solved questions helps keep SO tidy.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809878

Answer (score 8):

I believe the compiler thinks you are trying to pass in an class type into `sort` because you added the `[]` after array in your call to `sort` which is how you declare an array type.

Just change

```
a.sort(array[])
```

to

```
 a.sort(array)
```

because you have already initialized `array` as an `int[]` type/array earlier in your method.

You only need to add the `[]` during the intialization. After that, the variable name for an array is referenced just like the variable name for any other variable.

Comment: +1 That is a good interpretation of why the compiler might have generated that message. I couldn't think of a reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Your `sort (int[] vals)` takes an `int[]` parameter.

Your `int[] array` is already of that type, and you simply need to pass `array` by itself. The name of the variable is `array` and its type is `int[]`. When you pass the variable to a function, you refer to it by its name. There is no "`array[]`", that is not a valid construct.

Syntactically, `array[]` is invalid, but hypothetically if it were valid, the type I imagine it would be is `int` (the type of one of the elements) not `int[]`.

The ".class expected" compiler error is misleading. The `array[]` syntax is invalid, and I guess the compiler's confusion leads to an unexpected error message (edit: good explanations for the error are given in mdewitt and meriton's answers).

By the way, Java does support the syntax `int array[];` as an equivalent of `int[] array;`. Personally I never liked this ambiguity and I use the former syntax where possible. If you see this syntax, do not be confused -- the name is still `array` and the type is still `int[]`.

Answer (score 2):

> Assignment1.java:82: error: '.class' expected a.sort(array[]);

That means the error is on line 82 of Assignment1.java. That line reads:

```
  a.sort(array[]);
```

which clearly isn't valid java syntax. You can not postfix a variable with empty square brackets. If you mean to pass the array object, simply use the variable by itself:

```
  a.sort(array);
```

Put differently, there is no special syntax for passing an array. You can pass an array like any other object or primitive value.

Empty square brackets can only be used to denote an array type, in which case they follow the component type. If we take that interpretation, `array` would have to be a type rather than a variable, and `array[]` would denote a type rather than an expression. Of course, you can not pass a type in a method parameter, but you could pass the class object for that type:

```
  a.sort(array[].class);
```

That's what the compiler thinks you're trying to do. Of course, that's nonsense, because this wouldn't be type correct, as the sort methods expect an array rather than a class object, and array doesn't denote a type to begin with. Put differently, the compiler guessed wrong what you mean to say, and therefore confused you with an unrelated error message.